# Probability fruit basket problem

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, conditional-probability

Suppose we have two healthy but curiously mixed boxes of fruit, with one box containing 8 apples and 4 grapefruit and the other containing 15 apples and 3 grapefruit. One of the boxes is selected at random and a piece of fruit is picked (but not eaten) from the chosen box, with equal probability for each item in the box. The piece of fruit is returned and then once again from the same box a second piece is chosen at random. This is known as sampling with replacement. Model the chosen box with the random variable   , the first piece of fruit with the variable  1 , and the second piece with  2 .

What is the probability that the first piece of fruit is an apple given that the second piece of fruit was a grapefruit? How can the result of the second pick affect the probability of the first pick?

so what I did is i created a table for all independent probability. And when we talk of dependent probability. For eg for grapefruit being second choice i multiple it's value with independent value of apple as first pic for 1st n 2nd bag.

Is this correct ? can we say prob of 2nd being grapefruit i P(F1B1=a)*(P(F2B1=g)+P(F2B2=g)) + P(F1B2=a)*(P(F2B1=g)+P(F2B2=g))

or i have miss understood this ?

Comment: Hi, please follow the instructions for the [tag:self-study] tag by showing us what you’ve tried so far and where you’re stuck.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).