# Textbook probability theory Bayes exercise

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

I encountered the following question in one of my college textbooks:

> Suppose we have two healthy but curiously mixed boxes of fruit, with one box containing 8 apples and 4 grapefruit and the other containing 15 apples and 3 grapefruit. One of the boxes is selected at random and a piece of fruit is picked (but not eaten) from the chosen box, with equal probability for each item in the box. The piece of fruit is returned and then once again from the same box a second piece is chosen at random. This is known as sampling with replacement. Model the chosen box with the random variable $$, the first piece of fruit with the variable $1$, and the second piece with $2$.

> What is the probability that the first piece of fruit is an apple given that the second piece of fruit was a grapefruit? How can the result of the second pick affect the probability of the first pick?

Currently, I calculated both $P(F1)$ and $P(F2)$ using the standard formula:

$$
P(F1) = P(B1)*P(F1|B1)+P(B2)*P(F1|B2)=\frac{1}{2}*\frac{8}{12}+\frac{1}{2}*\frac{15}{18}=\frac{3}{4}
$$

$$
P(F2) = P(B1)*P(F2|B1)+P(B2)*P(F2|B2)=\frac{1}{2}*\frac{4}{12}+\frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{18}=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Now Í'm stuck at the part at which I assume I must use Bayes' Theorem to find $P(F1|F2)$ which is denoted by

$$
P(F1|F2)=\frac{P(F2|F1)*P(F2)}{P(F1)}
$$

However I seem to be unable to find a way to calculate $P(F2|F1)$, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Same question as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545888/) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545808/), except that this author has done a better job quoting his source, and has done some work on solving the problem.  (Consequently, I won't mark it as a duplicate.)  Presumably this is something that multiple students have been assigned in a class.